# Tensor transformation Formula Proof

Tags: coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, covariance

Ok so basically I am trying to prove that the following expression:

[image]

Can be written using matrices like this:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: It's pretty much defined that way.  I'm not clear what you're asking.   It's a little bit weird to write the $\cdot$ instead of just putting the symbols next to each other, but I think that's not your question.

Comment: Why does the $\lambda$ matrix become a $Q$ matrix? That change in notation seems pointless and confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that you need to know this,

$a_{ij}b_{jn} = (\textbf{a} \cdot  \textbf{b})_{in} = \textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{b}$

Note that the position of index $j $ .

$a'_{mn} = v_{mi}  v_{nj} a_{ij}$

and you want to show

$\textbf{a}' = \textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{v}^T $

So,

$a'_{mn} = v_{mi}  v_{nj} a_{ij} = $

$a'_{mn} =  v_{nj} v_{mi}  a_{ij} =$

$a'_{mn} =  v_{nj} (\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{a})_{mj} =$

$a'_{mn} =  (\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{a})_{mj}  v_{nj}  =$

$a'_{mn} =  (\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{a})_{mj}  v^T_{jn}  =$

$a'_{mn} =  (\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{v}^T)_{mn}  \implies$

$\textbf{a}' = \textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{v}^T $

Comment: oh thank u very much <3